# how to start hyper ledger fabric without fabric-samples?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am going to build my own hyperledger fabric network , but I cannot see how to start my project without the fabric-sample, because all the tutorials I found did not tell me how. How can I get those folders and stuffs for my own project? .

Answer (score 3):

You could go through the scripts of Fabric-samples to see what it does as a reference but in general the algorithm is the following:

- define the participants in your network in crypto-config.yaml and generate their crypto materials with either cryptogen (but not for production network!) or manually.
- define the network parameters like different policies, ordered type, consortium etc in configtx.yaml and generate a genesis block from it using configtxgen tool
- having that you may run required nodes like peers belonging to different organizations, orderers and certificate authorities servers and actually start the network, the channels, install chaincodes as it all referenced in Fabric docs: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/